# Write in a cell every value of a first cell in a row where a value was found

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Don't know how else to call this, but basically, in this example:

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wp7Iu.png)

I would need C2 to find out where John is located by finding the text "John" from C8 to C12, and then writing the value of "Mall, Home, Library" to C2 by using the JOIN function possibly.

I've tried many different combinations, and I can't seem to get it down. Hard to look for it as well, because I am not able to properly describe this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a similar sheet to yours and this formula works for me:

`=FILTER(B8:B12, REGEXMATCH(C8:C12, "John"))`

Does not use the `JOIN` function though.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I was looking for. Say, if I also wanted to search for multiple columns, not just one, would you be able to make a formula for that as well? For example, if I wanted to search for a match between cells C2:D12 with multiple containing 'John' and I wouldn't want the result to contain duplicates.